# Send a link in confirmation mail

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-webpages

I'm using these configurations:

```
WebMail.SmtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com";
WebMail.EnableSsl = true;
WebMail.SmtpPort = 587;
WebMail.UserName = "name";
WebMail.Password = "pass";
WebMail.From = "fromaddres";
```

Sending confirmation email with hyperlink returns me an HttpRequestValidationException.

I've tried to make test-mail page with WebMail.Send() method. Some code from there:

```
try{
    if(IsPost){
        WebMail.Send(
            to: Request.Form["emailAddress"],
            subject: Request.Form["emailSubject"],
            body: Request.Form["emailBody"],
            isBodyHtml: true
       );
       message = "Email sent!";
    }
}catch(HttpRequestValidationException){
}catch(Exception ex){
    message = "Email could not be send! Error: "+ex.Message;
}
```

If I write in 'emailBody' input a plain text. Email is sended correctly.

But if I write somewhere in input text any html tag e.g. hyperlink or paragraph, it returns me the same exception and says that the 'emailBody' input content could be potencially dangerous.

Could somebody say what I'm doing wrong or how to resolve this problem?

**EDIT**:

The solution was setting "isBodyHtml" parameter to false.
Erase all html tags from "emailBody" and just write plain text with url
(e.g. "Hi, visit this site: www.google.com")
In the received email i've got a text with link to desired site.

Anyway sending `<a>` link would be usefull.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your `Request.Form["emailBody"]` has html encoded string. You would probably need to convert the encoded HTML to raw html before it could be sent over email. You can use `WebUtility.HtmlDecode` ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee388354%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)) method to convert back to raw html.

```
        to: Request.Form["emailAddress"],
        subject: Request.Form["emailSubject"],
        body: WebUtility.HtmlDecode(Request.Form["emailBody"]),
```

Comment: Still the same exception. Is there any other way to do this besides disabling validation?

Answer (score 0):

That exception is thrown when potential malicious code are submitted through a request. In this case the HTML markup. [HttpRequestValidationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequestvalidationexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

*You can disable the request validation for your application by adding this to your web.config:

```
<configuration> 
  <system.web> 
    <pages validateRequest="false" /> 
  </system.web> 
</configuration>*
```

Note: **Always** sanitize your inputs.

**EDIT:**

I've tested the configuration above, and indeed it does not work.

If you decorate your method with `[ValidateInput(false)]` and add `requestValidationMode="2.0"` to the `<httpRuntime />` element you should be able to send e-mails with html content.

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

From my test config:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    ...
    <pages>
      ....
    </pages>
  </system.web>
```

From the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult SendMail(string param1)
{
    // code omitted due to brewity.
}
```

Comment: It didn't change nothing in my case. Any other ideas?

Comment: Ok, but what if I write in Web Pages?
I must use something instead of [ValidateInput(false)], because I don't have a controller.

I've found something about "Validation.Exclude" method [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scothu/archive/2010/10/06/web-pages-beta-2-request-validation.aspx), but I neither can use it nor find any documentation about it.

Comment: Could you try adding the `validateRequest="false"` to your `Page directive` at the top of the page? `<%@ Page validateRequest="false" %>`